# "One of my friends" vs "a friend of mine"

Tags: pronouns, possessives, semantics

The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, page 717, reads

> [16] quantified NP has scope over frequency adjunct
>
> *One of my friends has been sacked two or three times in the last few
> months*

When expressing the possessive, is there any difference between these two structures in general?

Do both imply that the same friend got sacked each time?

Comment: I don't sense a difference

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between the two constructions in most cases as far as meaning goes ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/mine_1?q=mine)); this is confirmed by the following ELL sources.

[question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/270/118547),
[its accepted answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/289/118547); it is useful to read all the answers to that question.

The construction is also used widely for the following words, as this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&content=%2A+of+mine&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfriend%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfriends%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bacquaintance%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwords%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfault%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bone%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbusiness%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bson%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bletter%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcousin%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2C*%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfriend%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfriends%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bacquaintance%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwords%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfault%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bone%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbusiness%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bson%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bletter%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcousin%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0) shows.

*acquaintance, words, cousin, fault, son, business, letter*

[image]

Plenty of other words can be found, so that there is none that seems to be excepted from this usage: job, book, car, girl, shirt, trousers, socks, pen , pencil, fate, etc.

One difference is found relative to the grammatical environment where the construction is found.

For instance "This, my red car, is the only vehicle I drive." is not a well established form, it is at best found very colloquial (user LPH's appraisal of the register).
If the comma is not used (making the pronoun "this" into a determiner) this sentence is in no way correct.

From the following source, [Google Books](https://books.google.fr/books?id=3ZivAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA47&dq=%22car+of+mine%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiftv378u3qAhV05-AKHequAI8Q6AEwAHoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22car%20of%20mine%22&f=false),  one sees that the construction "of mine" is helpful when the combination of the indefinite article (also "another") or of a demonstrative and the possessive is wanted (there are other cases: after "*any*" and "*what*" for instance).

[image]

This source confirms further that the structure "of mine" is not normally used unless there is "a post-head adjunct".

***LPH's examples***

- <s>The red shirt of mine was torn to pieces.</s> *not likely; instead, "My red shirt was torn to pieces."*
- The red shirt of mine in the washing machine is torn at the elbow.
- A red shirt of mine (that I wouldn't wear at all, not even for doing the dirtiest work,) was on the floor.
- This red shirt of mine is so old that I think I'll never wear it again.

***Google Books***

[ex. 1](https://books.google.fr/books?id=2OJ2VzbI7VsC&pg=PT98&dq=%22car+of+mine%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiftv378u3qAhV05-AKHequAI8Q6AEwAnoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22car%20of%20mine%22&f=false)
It had been approximately one week since I first began the massive undertaking of building this soapbox derby-car of mine.

[ex. 2](https://books.google.fr/books?id=0ryqWd7rKjkC&pg=PT31&dq=%22car+of+mine%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiftv378u3qAhV05-AKHequAI8Q6AEwCHoECDMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22car%20of%20mine%22&f=false) It was such a beautiful machine, this car of mine.

[ex. 3](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Vb6SBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT95&dq=%22job+of+mine%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQ9oKcg-7qAhVFqxoKHdP1DmgQ6AEwBXoECB4QAg#v=onepage&q=%22job%20of%20mine%22&f=false) I think my new friends could see how frustrated I was with this new job of mine, I really didn't fit it and I started to wonder if I had made a huge mistake by leaving the community.

[ex. 4](https://books.google.fr/books?id=HAviEKoOChcC&pg=PP38&dq=%22job+of+mine%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQ9oKcg-7qAhVFqxoKHdP1DmgQ6AEwC3oECDEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22job%20of%20mine%22&f=false) Another job of mine was cleaning the walk-in oven.

[ex; 5](https://books.google.fr/books?id=lYq2JDEcE6sC&pg=PA141&dq=%22fate+of+mine%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHvIvnhO7qAhUGCRoKHV7ACWoQ6AEwA3oECCcQAg#v=onepage&q=%22fate%20of%20mine%22&f=false) …and then had gone to Editha and my own supper (waited on by many a wondering, kindly one of these corded, russet Brothers), when that strange fate of mine overtook me once again.

[ex. 6](https://books.google.fr/books?id=RpQCAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA319&dq=%22fate+of+mine%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHvIvnhO7qAhUGCRoKHV7ACWoQ6AEwAnoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22fate%20of%20mine%22&f=false)  By what singular fate of mine , conscript fathers , shall I say it comes to pass , that for these twenty years there has not been an enemy to the public

[ex. 7, an exception](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ADybRDNiHxEC&pg=PA12&dq=%22car+of+mine%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiftv378u3qAhV05-AKHequAI8Q6AEwBnoECDIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22car%20of%20mine%22&f=false) I mean, I was no longer driving the piece-of-junk Japanese car of mine;

A second difference is found relative to the set of elements out of which one is selecting one or more. This point is well explained in [this source](https://books.google.fr/books?id=i2kCAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA439&dq=%22a+book+of+mine%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwir9_r97-3qAhXZAGMBHbOiD5EQ6AEwAHoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22a%20book%20of%20mine%22&f=false).

[image]

Comment: what about **"... of mine"** being _not only possession but also emotional attachment_?

Comment: @GJC I believe that the whole scope of what "mine" can qualify as associated to a person comprises the feelings and states of mind of that person, in particular emotional attachments.

Comment: @GJC Is the construction usable in the case of emotional attachements? Yes, it is used for "fear" for instance (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&content=fear+of+mine&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfear%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfear%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0) and I don't see why not use it for example in the case of the word "love".